# There are fewer than $q(q-1)/2$ rationals of the form $m/n$, with $n<q, m,n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ in any open interval about an irrational number $a$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

While studying the GRE Math Subject test, I came across a property in a proof that for the function 
                            $$f(x)=
                           \begin{cases}
                                0,      & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \cap(0,1)\\
                                \frac{1}{n},     & x=\frac{m}{n} 
                            \end{cases}
                        $$
 with $GCD(m,n)=1, n>0$, that $f$ is continuous on every irrational point in $I=(0,1)$, and discontinuous on the rationals there.

The property in question is the following:

Given a positive integer, $q$, and an irrational number $a$ in any open sub-interval of $I$ centred at $a$, there are fewer than $1+2+ \cdots + (q-1) = \frac{q(q-1)}{2}$ rationals of the form $\frac{m}{n}<1$ with $n<q$.

Can someone help me make sense as to why this might be true?

Comment: sure is a typo!  fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all starts with [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_approximation_theorem) (a short proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127641/rounding-to-fraction/2127773#2127773)). Everything else is just counting, with the $\frac{m}{n}<1 \Rightarrow 0<m < n$ constraint. E.g.
$$n=q \Rightarrow m \in \{1,...,q-1\}$$
$$n=q-1 \Rightarrow m \in \{1,...,q-2\}$$
$$...$$
$$n=2 \Rightarrow m \in \{1\}$$
Altogether, counting all the possible values for $m$, maximum $\frac{q(q-1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a crude estimate of the number of fractions with denominators less than or equal to $q$ in the entire interval $(0,1)$.  There is 1 fraction with denominator equal to 2, 2 fractions with denominator equal to 3, 3 fractions with denominator equal to 4, up to $q-1$ fractions with denominator equal to $q$.

Comment: @Shuri2060  It should definitely read something like "*fractions* of the form $\frac{m}{n}<1$ with $n<q$."

Comment: Yes. and it's fixed. And after reading it a couple more times and messing with some values...
Yes sharding4, denominators less than q.  derp.  For every integer $q$, there are $q-1$ fractions less than $1$ with denominator less than $q$.   _Obviously_ the number of fractions in for a given denominator will be one less than value of the denominator so the total number of such fractions, for a given $q$ will be less than $\frac{q(q-1)}{2}$. But _fewer_ than that will be co-prime. Thanks.  Apologies for asking a silly question and for the typo.